# How to check if an app is installed to my Shopify Store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I can see all of my installed apps in shopify admin/apps, but i want to check it using some code behind (from my rails app).

Is there any way to list all the installed apps in my Shopify Store

or check specific app if it's installed or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> check specific app if it's installed or not?

You can use [ShopifyAPI::Shop.current](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/shop.rb#L8). If the shop is not installed you'll get a `ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess` exception.

You'll also see `ActiveResource::ClientError`s for shops that are suspended (e.g. credit card expired) and `ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound` for dead shops.

Comment: Hi @Garvin, thanks for your answer. but it only gives Shop info no installed apps related :(